# Parsing and Recursion of SOAP response in SoapUI

Tags: web-services, soap, groovy, soapui

I have a SOAP response from a TestStep in SoapUI. I want to parse each value of a specific element in the response and send it as a parameter to a separate request call to another web service.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <searchResponse xmlns="urn:messages_2012_2.platform.webservices.technoplat.com">
        <platformCore:searchResult xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2012_2.platform.webservices.technoplat.com">
            <platformCore:searchRowList>
                <platformCore:searchRow xsi:type="tranSales:TransactionSearchRow" xmlns:tranSales="urn:sales_2012_2.transactions.webservices.technoplat.com">
                    <tranSales:basic xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2012_2.platform.webservices.technoplat.com">
                        <platformCommon:tranId>
                            <platformCore:searchValue>17678</platformCore:searchValue>
                        </platformCommon:tranId>
                    </tranSales:basic>
                </platformCore:searchRow>
                <platformCore:searchRow xsi:type="tranSales:TransactionSearchRow" xmlns:tranSales="urn:sales_2012_2.transactions.webservices.technoplat.com">
                    <tranSales:basic xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2012_2.platform.webservices.technoplat.com">                    
                        <platformCommon:tranId>
                            <platformCore:searchValue>17705</platformCore:searchValue>
                        </platformCommon:tranId>                   
                    </tranSales:basic>
                </platformCore:searchRow>
                <platformCore:searchRow xsi:type="tranSales:TransactionSearchRow" xmlns:tranSales="urn:sales_2012_2.transactions.webservices.technoplat.com">
                    <tranSales:basic xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2012_2.platform.webservices.technoplat.com">
                        <platformCommon:tranId>
                            <platformCore:searchValue>17777</platformCore:searchValue>
                        </platformCommon:tranId>
                    </tranSales:basic>
                </platformCore:searchRow>          
            </platformCore:searchRowList>
        </platformCore:searchResult>
    </searchResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

In the SOAP response above, I want to capture the values: 17678, 17705 and 17777 separately and send them as a parameter to another SOAP Request TestStep. Most people recommend using a groovy script for the recursion.

My questions are:
1. whats the best way to perform extraction of values from the SOAP response above and iterate and make a separate SOAPRequest TestStep in SoapUI?
2. Assuming each value is extracted in a Groovy TestStep, how can I feed those out to a "results.txt" kind of csv (name value pair) file outside.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I used before may be not the best.

1. parsing XML by XmlSluper.
   There are many ways to process XML (see: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Processing+XML)
2. use XmlParser and CSVWriter (opencsv) to convert XML to CSV
   I'd seen good example from here: http://blog.ktronline.com/2011/12/creating-csv-file-from-xml-using-groovy.html

Answer (score 0):

if you're using soapUI Pro the easiest way to do this is use the DataSource TestStep with a XML DataSource (see http://blog.smartbear.com/software-quality/bid/170520/How-to-Use-XML-DataSources-for-Response-Processing-in-soapUI for an example). If you're using the free version then scripting is your best option!

Good Luck!

/Ole